# How to download the entire PowerBi report as an excel

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

We have designed the report which has Pie and bars chart would need to download the entire report as an excel with the Chart representation.

**Currently, the report is embedded in the SharePoint page. Would need to download the report from the embedded page, using a Download button.**

DataSoruce: SharePoint list.
Report embedded in SharePoint Page.

Is there any way we can download the entire power bi report as excel?

Comment: A Power BI report is fundamentally different from an Excel file, so this doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is no export Report to Excel for standard Power BI reports.

With standard Power BI you cannot export the report as Excel, just PDF and PowerPoint. You can use Analyse in Excel to connect to the data model in the service, but you will have to recreate the visuals from the pivot table.

[image]

You can Export to Excel with Power BI Paginated Reports, but you'll need Premium, Premium Per User or Power BI Report Server to use this type of report. You'll be able to export in HTML, MHTML, PDF, XML, CSV, TIFF, Word and Excel.

If the report is embedded into an object like SharePoint you may be able to add an object that calls the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to). This will be dependant on the license type you have to access the API, Power BI Embedded EM SKU etc.
This will still result in the same export types for Power BI, PDF and PPTX, but also comes with and image file (PNG as default) and Power BI Premium/Per User options outlined above.

Comment: Currently, the report is embedded in the SharePoint page. Would need to download report from embedded page, using a Download button.

Comment: Updated answer to give an option via the PBI API. However for standard PBI reports there is no export to Excel.

Comment: will the below api can be used - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofile

Comment: Where to check the capacity

Comment: If your work space has a premium capacity it will show in the admin setting or a small Dimond icon on the workspace it self, and in the workspace setting